# symfony 2 3 бизнес логика

Tags: mvc, symfony

У меня следующая ситуация, есть View с таблицей с 30 колонками, в каждой колонке по 3-30 строк примерно следующего содержания:

```
<?php if($model->getSomeCheck()): ?>
    <button><?= $model->getSomeData() ?></button>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Вопрос**: Как это сделать в symfony если:

1. В *twig* нельзя вызывать методы из модели
2. В *Entity model* не советуют вообще хранить никакой логики кроме
   свойств и сеттеров и геттеров.
3. В расширении *twig* мне не удалось передать объект *entity* что-бы
   как-то обработать.
4. Если я буду вызывать методы модели в контроллере и передавать
   данные в вид, то это будет невозможно так как, у меня на каждую
   строку в таблице идет по 30 вызовов, строки выводятся в цикле и если
   я все буду данные вызовов буду хранить и передавать в вид то будет
   просто жесть.

Comment: Как связать запросы к бд и шаблонизацию, я не могу сразу все запросить у модели и отрендтрить, иначе у меня будет очень нечитабельный код

Comment: А кто вас научил, что представление должно вызывать методы модели? Контроллер должен взять у модели все необходимые данные и отдать их представлению

Comment: `на каждую строку в таблице идет по 30 вызовов` - вот это и нужно исправлять, это и есть жесть.

Comment: vp_arth а как иначе отрендрить 30 колонок, в каждой из которой для разных пользователей в зависимости от ситуации(от модели) по 2-4 варианта итогового html. Я не могу в модели же html генерировать. И так-же в контроллере в цикле по 30 переменных на строку в вид передавать.

Comment: Не html нужно генерировать, а массив.

Comment: пока нагуглил что можно сделать Service и определить его для Twig глобально

Comment: "И так-же в контроллере в цикле по 30 переменных на строку в вид передавать" Это и есть массив, у этого варианта огромные минусы: во первых это не класс, во вторых нечитабельный код, пока у меня 30 колонок разложены по полочкам(по файлам), я быстро могу найти колонку по имени файла, и перейти к методу в модели и узнать как получились такие данные + легче дебажить, это будет ад дебажить массив который вы хотите передавать.

Comment: Ой, всё... Вам виднее

Comment: Судя по [документации](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables), дёргать методы а-ля `$объект->getЧтоТо` ещё как можно, синтаксисом вида `объект.чтоТо`. Или ваш случай на это не ложится?

Comment: D-side да вы правы все работает, жаль в документации по 3 версии нету такого примера =) и у меня почему то когда проверял не сработало =)

Comment: vp_arth, это понятно что вы правы, но не для моего случая или у вас есть пример кода который показывает как можно решить мою задачу и не запутаться в своем же коде через пару недель?)

Comment: @ВалентинНаумов э-э-э, так Twig 2 вроде как последняя мажорная версия, о какой третьей версии речь?

Comment: D-side, но так как в PhpStorm не подсвечивает методы модели, то лучше делать через twig extension

Comment: @D-side, я не внимателен решил что это документация symfony а не twig

Comment: `"В документации по 3 версии нету такого примера"` - [Вот же](http://symfony.com/doc/current/templating.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема слишком синтетическая, на грани того, чтобы закрыть вопрос, как "Слишком общий". Суть проблемы не обозначена, поэтому количество вариантов решения слишком велико.

Вы можете завести итератор по вашим данным, или использовать какую-нибудь коллекцию Doctrine.

```
interface DataRow {
  public funtion getId();
  public funtion getName();
  public funtion getCreated();

  public funtion isSomeActionAllowed();
  public funtion getSomeActionId();
}

// In controller
return $this->render('default/top_articles.html.twig', [
  'rows' => DataRowIterator::some(),
]);


<table>
  <tr>
    <th>п.п.</th>
    <th>Наименование</th>
    <th>Дата</th>
    <th>someAction</th>
  </tr>
  {% for item in rows %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{item.id}}</td>
      <td>{{item.name}}</td>
      <td>{{item.created | date("d.m.Y")}}</td>
      <td>
        {% if item.someActionAllowed %}
          <button class="actionButton" data-action-id="{{item.someActionId}}">someAction</button>
        {%endif%}
      </td>
    </tr>
  {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> В twig нельзя вызывать методы из модели

Неправда ваша. **Можно.**

В [документации к Twig 2](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/templates.html#variables) сказано:

> [...] `foo.bar` на уровне PHP делает следующее:
>
> - проверяет, является ли `foo` массивом и имеет ли он элемент `bar`;
> - если нет, то если `foo` объект, имеет ли он свойство `bar`;
> - если нет, и если `foo` объект, имеет ли он метод `bar` (даже если `bar` конструктор - используйте `__construct()`);
> - если нет, и если `foo` объект, имеет ли он метод `getBar`;
> - если нет, и если `foo` объект, имеет ли он метод `isBar`;
> - если нет, и если `foo` объект, имеет ли он метод `hasBar`;
> - если нет, вернуть значение `null`.

Comment: Как один из вариантов, хороший способ, но наверно в symfony есть какой-то способ сделать это более элегантно?

Comment: @ВалентинНаумов мы никуда не торопимся, подождите, может придёт кто-то, кто всё-таки хоть что-нибудь знает про Symfony, в отличие от меня.